# Git command to add all projects to Git Desktop under /PROJECTS

Tags: android, c++, git, github, gitkraken

This is a real easy question, but I am having difficulties getting this to work. I have a dir /PROJECTS that contains all of my different projects. I am using this local and remote.

I just need the command to say import all applications under /PROJECTS to any GitGui I am using. I hve decided to work with GitKraken s well as 
Github Desktop.

Thanks in advance-

Regards-

Chris Russo

Answer (score 0):

In Gitkraken it doesn't actually import projects. It's more like a git repository browser.

So if you have a bunch of git repositories in a /PROJECTS directory, then in GK go to File->Preferences...->General and set the "Project Directory" to "/PROJECTS".

Then on the main GUI screen of GK, the repositories in /PROJECTS will be shown on the buttons in the upper left corner.

You can also use the "File -> Open repo -> Browse for more repos" to find repos located anywhere on your machine.

If by "import" you mean you want to convert directories to git repos, then use "File -> Open repo -> Browse for more repos" to open each directory you want to convert to a repo, and it will ask if you want to create a new repository there.